# Multiserver administration - passing maintenance plans to clustered instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, multi-server-admin

SQL Server 2019 MSX/TSX environment. TSX servers are clustered instances. MSX is not. There is a SQL integration service on each of the nodes in the cluster. I create a maintenance plan on the MSX and when i try to push it to the TSX i get this error:

> Message
> [000] Failed to import Maintenance Plan 'MaintenancePlanMSA' from MSX: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumeratorException: Failed to retrieve data for this request. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Parameter 0 is incorrect for this statement.
> The statement has been terminated.
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataReader(String query, SqlCommand& command)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.SetConnectionAndQuery(ExecuteSql execSql, String query)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataProvider(StringCollection query, Object con, StatementBuilder sb, RetriveMode rm)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillData(ResultType resultType, StringCollection sql, Object connectionInfo, StatementBuilder sb)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillDataWithUseFailure(SqlEnumResult sqlresult, ResultType resultType)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.BuildResult(EnumResult result)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DiskFile.GetData(EnumResult erParent)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
> --- End of inner

I tried to add all agent service users as sysadmin, didn't work.

The funny thing is that the job, under the maintenance plan, appears on the TSX.

When i create a standalone job and push it to the target, the job appears on the TSX(?!).

Hope someone can help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JohnnyP.
I know that a long time has passed - but maybe someone will need it.
This error is related to the sys.dm_os_enumerate_filesystem() function launched without the @Path parameter.
In my case, the error appeared due to the fact that I did not specify the folder for the job execution log.
If you create a maintenance plan by wizard, then you need to tick  the 'write and report to a text file' and select folder on the "Select Report Options" window.

Comment: OMG, i don't believe it, it worked... I would kiss you right now. This is new info for me that a report location in a maint plan is obligatory for MSA. Thank you very much!